# Component/Module placement issue in experience editor in Sitecore 8.1

Tags: sitecore-client, experience-editor, presentation

We are facing very strange issue. On a page we have one Banner(B) and two Container module/component C1,C2
Here is sequence on page:

B

C1

C2

In Experience Editor

when I add one Container module below C1 and save , it move upward and finally placed between B & C1 ( It should placed below C1 )

when I add one Container module below C2 and save , it move upward and finally placed between C1 & C2 ( It should placed below C2 )

Basically it's multilingual website( EN , ES ) so basically it's working fine in EN but not in ES

Any body might have faced this issue please suggest

Comment: so are you saying that in EN language the module placement happens as expected and in ES language it jump one level higher then expected?

Comment: yes basically for EN I change the language version in top right to English and click on experience editor button in top ribbon and working fine
For ES I change the language version in top right to Spanish and click on experience editor button in top ribbon. In this case not working...
just thinking it's general issue or I need to debug my code might be I'm getting any exception

Comment: that is very odd, only other thing i can think of would be if somehow those placeholders are disabled or not allowed for the ES language. Can you check that if the placholders are set correctly for all languages.

Comment: sure I will check that...for this we re-build the page again in Exp. Editor and it's working fine now